# ARCore is detecting the image very erratically

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

We are using ARCore for your Ar app and the detection of augmented images is working very erratically.

We have images with 100% trust and most of the time they are not detected although sometimes they are... In IOS all works well and as expected.9

Any idea or tip on why this is happening?

Comment: On which device are you working? Do you see this across multiple android devices? Does it help if you add the size hint? 

I assume that the 100% trust is referring to the score from the arcore Image tool?